# How to display the output as the input with a fractional delay?

Tags: matlab, digital-communications, downsampling, delay

I am trying to introduce a fractional delay in my input vector x[n] so the output is something like y[n]=x[n-M/N]. I am not supposed to use the MATLAB fracdelay function.So, I used sampling and delay. The three steps I followed are:

1)Upsample the input by M.

2)Delay the upsampled version.

3)Downsample the output obtained in step 2 to get y[n].

However I can't get the correct fractionally delayed output. Can someone please help? Here is my MATLAB code:

```
x=[1 2 3 4 1 3 4 5 6 3];
up=upsample(x,2);

z=zeros(1,10);

for n=1:10; 
   k=n+1;
   z(1,k)=up(1,n);
end

y=downsample(z,2,1);
subplot(411);
stem(x)
subplot(412)
stem(up)
subplot(413);
stem(z)
subplot(414);
stem(y)
```

Here is how my output looks like:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the built-in `upsample()` and `downsample()` functions for the obvious purposes. While for delaying the signal you'll have to create a separate index vector because in MATLAB you can't keep track of index without this step. Then simply introduce the fractional delay in the index vector and plot your original signal against this delayed version of the index vector.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using "upsample", which merely inserts zeros in between the original samples, instead of "interp", which upsamples and then low-pass filters.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably easier to convolve with a (fractionally) shifted sinc, or to do the same in the fourier domain, that is, multiply with the frequency response of a linear phase filter, which is rather easy to construct. Then you'd wrap the ends, however. There is an IIR version of fractional delay, too.